# Erro 403 disallowed_useragent, ao logar com google no navegador mobile usando angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-fire-2

Olá, estou utilizando o pacote angularfire2 v4.0.0-rc.2 em um projeto angular4 publicado no firebase.

Integrei os logins do facebook e do google e ambos estão funcionando perfeitamente no navegador do pc e também em um app android nativo.

Ao tentar logar utilizando o navegador do telefone, recebo uma tela de erro:
[image: Erro no navegador do celular]

Encontrei vários posts sobre o google ter avisado que iria bloquear o acesso via webview, porém, isso faz muito tempo e a biblioteca angularfire2 já deveria estar atualizada para isso, provavelmente.

Tentei mudar o método de login via popup para login com redirect mas o resultado foi a mesma tela de erro no navegador do celular.

Comment: Pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38664350

Comment: Obrigado, Jefferson, mas não se aplica ao meu projeto

Comment: Percebi agora que instalando outro navegador (chrome) no celular o login com google volta a funcionar... Então talvez um work around seja fazer uma lista de user-agents bloqueados e avisar ao usuário que o navegador dele é incompatível... =\